# Java regex to match an exact number of dashes

Tags: java, regex

In my Markdown-like text, I want to replace exactly three dashes (`---`) with an emdash entity, but I don't want to replace four dashes.

How can I write this as a regex?

I tried this:

```
String input = "--- This---example----and--another.---";
String expected = "&#8212; This&#8212;example----and--another.&#8212;";
assertEquals(expected, input.replaceAll("-{3}", "&#8212;"));
```

But it gives me:

```
&#8212; This&#8212;example&#8212;-and--another.&#8212;
```

Instead of what I want:

```
&#8212; This&#8212;example----and--another.&#8212;
```

I want it to work when three dashes appear at the start or end of a line or with *any* surrounding characters (other than dashes)—i.e. not just when surrounded by alphanumerics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use lookarounds to make sure only 3 dashes are matched:

```
input.replaceAll("(?<!-)-{3}(?!-)", "&#8212;")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yG2Ey2/1)

The `(?<!-)` *negative lookbehind* will fail the match once a `-` is before the  3 dashes, and `(?!-)` *negative lookahead* will fail the match if there is a `-` after 3 dashes.

Comment: Oh man, I didn't even know about those zero-width lookahead / lookbehind constructs. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

You can tell it that the character around the 3 dashes mustn't be another one:

`replaceAll("[^-]-{3}[^-]", ...)`

Comment: This will also match the previous and following characters, so it can't be used in the context of a replacement.

Comment: This (1) *requires* existence of non-dashes around `---` so it will fail if `---` will be placed at start or end of string, (2) will also remove those surrounding non-dashes which can cause other problems like in case of `a---b---c` where `b` will be removed with `a---b` so it will prevent you from using it again to match `b---c`.